# How can I repurpose the time spent reading random stuff on the Internet to improve my Chinese?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese

This is my situation most days:

1. I'm too tired to study Chinese...
2. ...but it's too early to go to bed...
3. ...I know, I'll read random stuff on the Internet.

I feel like I could should be utilizing this time for some kind of light Chinese practice, but I don't have the energy for active study.  Perhaps there's some suitable reading material, or games or apps that I'm unaware of.

(If relevant, I'm currently studying HSK5, maybe about 20% of the way through.)

**Question**: How can I repurpose the time spent reading random stuff on the Internet to improve my Chinese?

I'm not sure: maybe it's best to have "down time", or maybe it's not possible to meaningfully improve without actively working.

Comment: https://thechinaproject.com/2023/07/17/10-chinese-language-podcasts-you-should-listen-to/ Podcasts are a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to waste time on the Internet, you can at least do it at Chinese, especially when you're already at HSK 5. Search for Chinese-language keywords on Baidu and Youku. Or, browse Google News and Wikipedia with the language settings in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Becky from the past, future you has started to use [65Words](https://65words.com/) to "productively waste time".

It's a bit like Twitter for language learners.  At the time of writing, the website is in very early stages of development, but you can submit your writing.  As the name suggests, you're encouraged to submit 65 words of your writing in your target language daily:

> 65 Words is a challenge for writing 65+ words daily in the language you’re learning.

There are other writing websites, like [LangCorrect](https://langcorrect.com/), where you can get corrections.  However, 65Words (currently) doesn't obligate you to correct other people's writing in return.

For Chinese, another way to "productively waste time" is to answer questions on [Zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/) (sometimes described as "Chinese Quora").